# An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'SQLitePCLRaw.core' from source 'nuget.org'. Sequence contains no elements

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2022

I'm encountering some issues with my nuget packages in VS.2022

If I try to install a newer version of ANY package (or a new package) I get this in the output
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green.1.1.15' with respect to project 'XXX', targeting '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile75'
An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'SQLitePCLRaw.core.1.1.14' from source 'D:\TFS\XXX\XXX\packages'.
Sequence contains no elements

If I use the Package Manager Console and try to force an update all with the command "Update-Package" I get the following error message.

Update-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'SQLitePCLRaw.core' from source 'nuget.org'.
Sequence contains no elements
At line:1 char:1

- Update-Package
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
  ```

Not sure what I am doing wrong :-(

Below is the content of one of my project files

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>11.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{119FC141-E66C-48FA-A8B4-3D522E8D4D31}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>TechAssist</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TechAssist</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile75</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <NoWarn>CS4014;CS0168;CS1998</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\CarouselView.FormsPlugin.5.0.2\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10\CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.17.3.35304, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.17.3\lib\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform, Version=3.17.3.35304, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.17.3\lib\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Connectivity, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugin.Connectivity.3.2.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.Connectivity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugin.Connectivity.3.2.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.DeviceInfo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo.4.1.1\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.DeviceInfo.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.ExternalMaps, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugin.ExternalMaps.4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.ExternalMaps.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.ExternalMaps.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugin.ExternalMaps.4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.ExternalMaps.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Geolocator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugin.Geolocator.4.5.0.6\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.Geolocator.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Media, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugin.Media.4.0.1.5\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.Media.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Messaging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugins.Messaging.5.2.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.Messaging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Messaging.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xam.Plugins.Messaging.5.2.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.Messaging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Permissions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Plugin.Permissions.3.0.0.12\lib\netstandard1.0\Plugin.Permissions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SignaturePad.Forms, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms.3.0.0\lib\netstandard1.0\SignaturePad.Forms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLite-net">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\sqlite-net-pcl.1.6.292\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\SQLite-net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green, Version=1.1.14.520, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a84b7dcfb1391f7f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green.1.1.14\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, Version=1.1.14.520, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8226ea5df37bcae9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green.1.1.14\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.1.14.520, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.core.1.1.14\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.527436\lib\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Platform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.527436\lib\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.527436\lib\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
 ...
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.527436\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.527436\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.527436\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.527436\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to install this package of version 1.1.14 on my side:

[image]

You can follow the below troubleshooting steps:

**1, The package source.**

The error you share show that you have two source, one source is D:\TFS\XXX\XXX\packages and another source is nuget.org.

Please check whether the first source on your side has the package you want, that source looks like local source.

And make sure the second source url is correct, it should be:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

You can use this command to check the nuget source on your side:

`nuget source`

**2, Network**

In this situation, please also make sure the network or network settings on your side is no problem.

You can try to install/update other packages to check whether they also have the same problem.

**3, Project Configuration.**

In this situation, you can try to create a new project. For example, console app project, and then try to install/update that package to this console app project to check whether the same issue still exist.

If possiable, please also share the project file content on your side(If you are writing C#, it should be .csproj file).

Comment: 1) local packages is present and nuget url is. Nuget packages are working in all my other projects
2) Network is also ok since nuget are working in all other projects
3) Nuget package can be installed and up/downgraded in a different project
     I include the project file above (removed all unnecessary parts)

Comment: @user1627384 Hi, just want to confirm, you mentioned "Nuget package can be installed and up/downgraded in a different project", what is the package you testing in that different project, still "SQLitePCLRaw.core"? If not, you can try to clean the nuget cache, uninstall the package via "Uninstall-Package SQLitePCLRaw.core -Force" and then reinstall it.

Comment: Hi, It is indeed the same package, tried clean nuget cache(then restart VS.Net), did not work. Unistalling it send me down the rabbit hole I'm afraid. Can't re-install it on my PCL project -> Invalid portable frameworks for '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile75'. A portable framework must have at least one framework in the profile.    
Not sure how to fix that one either sinde Profile75 is not even listed.
If have this in my pcl project file :     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile75</TargetFrameworkProfile>